# Skip the download of artifacts (with Maven) if it is not available in the repository

Tags: maven

Is it possible to skip the download of artifacts when none of the repositories defined in the pom file don't contain it? I realize that this might result in incorrect builds but is the option there anyway? 
I was trying to download the sources for all my dependencies using

```
mvn dependency:sources
```

but since some of the sources are not available, the maven process gets stuck in the middle. I have tried using the -fn option but that too does not stop it from getting stuck in the middle of the operation.

Answer (score 0):

If you define and need an artifact, your project cannot build without it and it would not make sense to be able to skip it.

If you do not need the dependency, you can delete it or use exclude if it is only a transitive dependency (i.e. one you get by using another dependency but do not need yourself).

If you do have the dependency locally, you can install it to your local repository, or if you know your container (application server) will provide it you can set it to scope provided.